# Explosão de Caracteres no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho a base de clientes, e a de notas por cliente:

```
   COD  CLIENTE
    128  JOAO
    129  MARIA
    130  DULCE


    NOTA
    234.123.334.128.50
    235.124.338.128.49
```

Nota-se que o código do cliente está inserido no número da nota, que no caso é o penúltimo conjunto antes do último ponto (128).

Como faço para "explodir" esses 3 números do código na tabela de notas para relacionar com o código registrado na minha base de cliente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma função no Oracle:

```
create or replace function GetToken( 
   tokenstring in varchar,
   tokenpos in number,
   delim in varchar )
   return varchar
is
   x number;
   i number;
   j number;
begin
  x := 1;
  i := 0;
  j := 0;
  while (i < TokenPos)
  loop
    j := x;
    while (x <= length( TokenString )) and ( substr( TokenString, x, 1 ) <> Delim) 
    loop
       x := x + 1;
    end loop;
    i := i + 1;
    x := x + 1;
  end loop;
  return trim(substr(TokenString, j, x - j - 1));
end;
```

Agora você selecionar as partes como quer assim:

Passe à funcão a string, a posição que quer e o delimitador.

```
select gettoken( '234.123.334.128.50', 4, '.' ) from dual
```

Comment: Foi de muita ajuda,  muito obrigado.